# ad " and ' inside ng-pattern html

Tags: angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I have a ng pattern like this `^[^#'"/]+$` to not allow the use of / " ' and #

i would like to add it inside the `ng-pattern='/^[^#'"/]+$/'` bug since there is the " and ' it break my string, and any attempt I made to fix this, it doesn't work.

How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to define the regex in your controller:

```
$scope.regex = "/^[^#'\"/]+$/";
```

Note that we only have to escape the double quote.  Then, apply it in the HTML element which is using `ng-pattern`:

```
ng-pattern="{{regex}}"
```